Java and Mockito Testing: ValidatableResponse and ValidatableResponseOptions
I'm relatively new to Java testing and have a problem. I'm about to test a Rest client.
I tested successfully all methods - put, get, delete. After I extended my delete method for a specific purpose I get an exception I cant solve:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponseOptions$MockitoMock$Alt0YnEv cannot be cast to class io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponse (io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponseOptions$MockitoMock$Alt0YnEv and io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponse are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Here is my code:
//the method to test
/**
 * Sends a delete request to given endpoint
 *
 * @param endpoint   Rest endpoint
 * @param parameters valueName=value, valueName2=value2 ... (optional)
 * @return ValidatableResponse
 */
public ValidatableResponse getJSONResourceDELETE2ArrayParams(String endpoint, String... parameters) {
    if(parameters.length > 1) {
        Response response = given()
                .cookie(this.cookie)
                .spec(getJsonRequestSpecification())
                .params(parameters[0], parameters[1])
                .when()
                .delete(this.injectionManager.inject(endpoint));

        cookie = extractCookie(response);

        return response
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This method needs at least two parameter");
    }
}

// the test
private void initRestAssured() {
    restClient.setLogging(RestClient.Logging.ALL);
    mockedRa.when(RestAssured::given).thenReturn(requestSpecification);
    when(requestSpecification.auth().preemptive().basic(anyString(), anyString())
            .multiPart(file)).thenReturn(requestSpecification);
    when(requestSpecification.cookie(cookie)).thenReturn(requestSpecification);
    when(requestSpecification.spec(any())).thenReturn(requestSpecification);
    when(requestSpecification.queryParams(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(requestSpecification);
    when(requestSpecification.when()).thenReturn(requestSpecification);
    when(requestSpecification.get()).thenReturn(response);
    when(requestSpecification.body(Mockito.any(File.class))).thenReturn(requestSpecification);
    when(injectionManager.inject(anyString())).thenReturn("something injected");
    when(requestSpecification.body(anyString())).thenReturn(requestSpecification);
    when(requestSpecification.post("something injected")).thenReturn(response);
    when(response.then()).thenReturn(validatableResponse);
    when(validatableResponse.statusCode(200)).thenReturn(validatableResponse);
    when(validatableResponseOptions.statusCode(200)).thenReturn(validatableResponse);
    when(validatableResponse.contentType(ContentType.JSON)).thenReturn(validatableResponse);
    when(validatableResponse.extract()).thenReturn(extractableResponse);
    when(extractableResponse.response()).thenReturn(response);
    when(response.as(String.class)).thenReturn("returned");
}

// TODO find issue with Validate Response
@Test
void testGetJSONResourceDELETE2ArrayParamsGivenEndPointAndParas_thenDelete() {
    // Given
    initRestAssured();
    String param1 = "id";
    String param2 = "name";
    String[] parameters = new String[2];
    parameters[0] = param1;
    parameters[1] = param2;

    // When
    restClient.getJSONResourceDELETE2ArrayParams(endpoint, parameters[0], parameters[1]);

    // Then
    verify(injectionManager, times(1)).inject(endpoint);
    verify(requestSpecification, times(1)).delete();
}

I would be happy for any solution suggested :)

some where in the mock you are returning ValidatableResponseOptions mock in place of ValidatableResponse mock
